# MSCK repair table failing for schema tables

Tags: hadoop, hive

My hive table name is in the below format:

***schema_name.hive_table_name***

***eg: schema1.abc;***

Now when I try to do MSCK repair table on the above hive table it throws below error.

`Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
FAILED: ParseException line 1:28 missing EOF at '.' near 'schema_name'`

Below is the command I used:

`hive -e "MSCK repair table schema_name.hive_table_name"`

Could any one help on this?

Comment: The syntax is fine and should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below statement:

`hive -e "use schema_name;MSCK repair table hive_table_name"`

This allows to add partition to hive with the specific schema mentioned .
It worked for me.

Thanks